# mongodb サブドキュメントの配列データの$andクエリがphpで表現できない

Tags: php, mongodb

PHP / mongod 初心者です。
mongodbのPHPによる検索に行き詰まっています。

**状況**
mongodbに以下の6ドキュメントが存在しています。

```
db.mongo_test01.find({},{_id: 0}).sort({"Data.Value": 1})
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 100 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 200 } ] }
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 101 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 201 } ] }
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 102 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 202 } ] }
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 103 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 203 } ] }
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 104 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 204 } ] }
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 105 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 205 } ] }
```

このcollectionに対してmongoclientにて以下の検索を実施します。

```
db.mongo_test01.find({$and:[{"Data":{$elemMatch:{"Name":"Japan","Value":{$gte:103}}}},{"Data":{$elemMatch:{"Name":"US","Value":{$lte:203}}}}]},{_id: 0})
{ "Data" : [ { "Name" : "Japan", "Value" : 103 }, { "Name" : "US", "Value" : 203 } ] }
```

結果は１ドキュメントで期待どおりです。

そこでこのクエリを以下のphpで表現してみました。

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$filter = ['$and' => [["Data" => ['$elemMatch' => ["Name" => "Japan","Value" => ['$gte'=>103]]]],["Data" => ['$elemMatch' => ["Name" => "US","Value" => ['$gte'=>203]]]]]];

$options = [
  'projection' => ['_id' => 0]
];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('test.mongo_test01', $query);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
  var_dump($document);
  foreach ($document->Data as $data) {
    print ($data->Name ."<br/>");
  }
}
?>
```

結果は

```
object(stdClass)#7 (1) { ["Data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "Japan" ["Value"]=> float(105) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(2) "US" ["Value"]=> float(205) } } } Japan
US
object(stdClass)#10 (1) { ["Data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "Japan" ["Value"]=> float(104) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(2) "US" ["Value"]=> float(204) } } } Japan
US
object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["Data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "Japan" ["Value"]=> float(103) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(2) "US" ["Value"]=> float(203) } } } Japan
US
```

と３ドキュメントが出力されて、mongoclientの結果と一致しません。
PHPの$filterの書き方に問題があると思いますが、よくわかりません。

どなたかご教授をお願いします。

**環境**
mongodb 4.0.4
PHP 5.6.39 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2019 16:46:33)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

Comment: 書き間違いなのかもしれませんが、mongoclient でのクエリが `{"Name":"US","Value":{$lte:203}}` となっているの対して、PHP でのクエリが `["Name" => "US","Value" => ['$gte'=>203]]` となっています。ここは `'$lte'=>203`  とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘どおりのプログラムミスでした。PHPの連想配列の書き方に自信がなくて式そのもののミスを見落としておりました。助かりました